# How to use Cordova plugins in browser?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, cordova-plugins

I build web and mobile (hybrid) application using Ionic framework. I use [cordova-plugin-crop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/) and [cordova-camera-plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/). They works fine in mobile application. Is it possible to use them in web application (in browser) on mobile devices?

Now I'm checking platform in JS code:

```
if (this.platform.is('core')) {
    // use web libraries for uploading and crop images
} else {
    // use @ionic-native cordova plugins
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The cordova-plugin-crop is only available on iOS and Android: [Ionic Crop plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/).

Cordova-plugin-crop supported platforms:

- iOS
- Android

Cordova-camera-plugin is available within the browser too: [Cordova Plugin Camera](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/).

Cordova-camera-plugin supported platforms:

- Android
- BlackBerry
- Browser
- Firefox
- FireOS
- iOS
- Windows
- WP8
- Ubuntu

> First off, be sure to note that the 'Quirks' information for the Camera plugin clearly points out that only Base64 image URIs are returned by the plugin. Normally Cordova devs recommend against that, but if you want to test on the Browser platform you'll need to use it.

[Raymond Camden using cordova plugins in browser](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old I know, but in case you were led here trying to look for an answer, I managed to make it work by running:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

Of course you need to have the camera plugin installed via npm install with the commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```